# How should I access the file system of the VSCode's user?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I am making a VSCode extension. It should read and modify files of user's file system. Should I do it with node's `fs` or should I use some VSCode's interface/API for this?

If the latter is correct then what is the API namespace I need (workspace or something)?

If the former is okay, how can I really use `fs`? What if the user does not have node.js installed? Or is it always installed with VSCode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends.

In general use vscode's `TextDocument` api for:

- Reading text files from the workspace. This api ensures that you always read the current state of the file (even if it has not been saved to disk yet).
- Modifying text file content in the workspace. You can also use `save` to write a modified file back to disk.
- Reading resources from file system providers

Use `fs` for:

- Reading and writing files that are outside of the workspace.
- Reading and writing files that should not be tracked by VS Code. Opening a `TextDocument` can cause VS Code and its extension to try processing the file.
- Reading and writing binary files.

[This api proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48034) would also be of interest for you. It would enable more low level file reading/writing directly using VS Code.

(Also, you can always safely use node since VS Code includes a copy for extensions to use)

Comment: The proposal has been accepted. One can now write `vscode.workspace.fs.readFile`/`writeFile`/`readDirectory`/etc. See also: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/fsconsumer-sample