# What Visual Studio Code extension API should be used to add folders and move files in a Visual Studio Code workspace?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write an extension that will:

- Read the folders and files in the current workspace
- Reorganise those files by creating new folders and moving the files into them

So I need an API to do the above. I am not clear on whether I should use

- the standard `fs` node module,
- the [File System Provider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider) or
- the `workspace` namespace.

I read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53559240/how-should-i-access-the-file-system-of-the-vscodes-user), but it doesn't say what to use to create folders and move files within the workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`FileSystemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider) is to be used if you want to serve files from non-local storage like FTP sites or virtual file systems inside remote devices and present them to Visual Studio Code as storage directories. The `FileSystemProvider` is a view/controller of the remote storage. In other words, you have to implement all the file manipulation operations by communicating with the remote storage.

If you want to just manipulate the files in the current workspace and also be able to use URI's from `FileSystemProvider`s, you use [`vscode.workspace.fs`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystem).

You can also use the Node.js `fs` module, but that only handles local disk workspaces (URI's with scheme `file:`). I recommend to use the *synchronous* versions of the `fs` methods. I had some troubles using the asynchronous `fs` methods in Visual Studio Code (I did not know of `vscode.workspace.fs` at that time).

Answer (score 0):

I found [extension.ts, sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/fsprovider-sample/src/extension.ts) for implementing `FileSystemProvider` provided by Microsoft. 
The below steps are provided which helps you understand how to create a new folder (`createDirectory`) and move files within the workspace (using the `copy` command, copying all files in an old folder to a new folder and use the `delete` command if you don’t wish for files to remain in the old folder).

1. The first step in `FileSystemProvider` is to **register the filesystem provider** for a given scheme using `registerFileSystemProvider`:

```
     const memFs = new MemFS();

     context.subscriptions.push(
              vscode.workspace.registerFileSystemProvider('memfs', memFs, {
                    isCaseSensitive: true
        }));
```

2. Next is to **register the command** `registerCommand` to perform your operations in FileSystemProvider like `readDirectory`, `readFile`, `createDirectory`, `copy`, `delete`.

```
context.subscriptions.push(
              vscode.commands.registerCommand('memfs.init', _ =>
             {
               #TODO: add required functionalities

          }));
```

- **Read folders and read files**

```
      for (const [name] of memFs.readDirectory(vscode.Uri.parse('memfs:/'))) {
                    memFs.readFile(vscode.Uri.parse(`memfs:/${name}`));
                }
```

- **Create the new folder**

```
memFs.createDirectory(vscode.Uri.parse(`memfs:/folder/`));
```

- **Move files to newly created folder**. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a separate move file command, but you can use the *Copy* command to copy to the new folder and then delete:

  **COPY**
  `copy(source: Uri, destination: Uri, options: {overwrite: boolean})`

  **DELETE**

```
     context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('memfs.reset', _ => {
               for (const [name] of memFs.readDirectory(vscode.Uri.parse('memfs:/'))) {
                    memFs.delete(vscode.Uri.parse(`memfs:/${name}`));
               }

            }));
```